# Find vectors u and v such that W = Span{u,v}

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $W$ be the set of all vectors of the form
>
> $\begin{bmatrix}s-t\\2s+t\\0\\t\end{bmatrix}$
>
> Find vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $W =$ Span{$u,v$}

How can I do this? Any advice woulds be great

Comment: Try expressing a vector of that form as a linear combination of two arbitrary vectors in $R^4$.

Comment: As noted by @enzotib, if these resulting vectors that you find are linearly independent, they span the space. Do you know how to check if vectors are linearly independent ?

Comment: as long as it is not the trivial solution yes

Comment: Ok, then you got it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\vec v=(s-t,2s+t,0,t)=s(1,2,0,0)+t(-1,1,0,1)$$
In other words, the vectors $\vec v$ are all linear combinations of the vectors $(1,2,0,0)$ and $(-1,1,0,1)$.
Therefore, $W = \text{span}\{(1,2,0,0),(-1,1,0,1)\}$.

Comment: AWesome explanation, now i understand how to do these lol thx @Emma

Answer (score 2):

$$
(s-t,2s+t,0,t)=(s,2s,0,0)+(-t,t,0,t)=s(1,2,0,0)+t(-1,1,0,1)
$$

Comment: In order for this to be a complete solution, you also need to test the linear independency of the two vectors.

Comment: This doesn't deserve to be downvoted